# Why ++ becomes -+-+-+- : string.gsub "strange" behavior

Tags: replace, lua

Why `++` becomes `-+-+-+-` ?

I'd like to clean a string from double operating signs. How should I process ?

```
String = "++"
print (String ) -- -> ++
String = string.gsub( String, "++", "+")
print (String ) -- -> + ok
String = string.gsub( String, "--", "+")
print (String ) -- -> +++ ?
String = string.gsub( String, "+-", "-")
print (String ) -- -> -+-+-+- ??
String = string.gsub( String, "-+", "-")
print (String ) -- -> -+-+-+- ??? ;-)
```

Comment: Look at each result separately.

Comment: Ok, I put each step in my example. I don't understand why `+` becomes `+++` at second step ? I missed something ?

Comment: `-` in [lua patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1) is a metacharacter.

Comment: I will use a `%`. Thank you.

Comment: @Tarass But now you know *which* exact pattern(s) causes the non-expected results - and can formulate a hypothesis/question with specific context. Always try to break down the problem. See [string.gsub](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial) - as at this point, with a single function returning 'unexpected results', the hypothesis should be about incorrect assumptions about usage of gsub - and follow the linked resources to read up about patterns.

Comment: I agree with you. I read about string.gsub a short synthesis, I didn't imagine there could be magic characters. As you said to that there is, looked further and found %. I didn't see, at first, the link you gave me and I found % and other explanaition that will be very helpfull for what I have to do. Thank you very much for your consern and your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core problem is that `gsub` operates on *patterns* (Lua's minimal regular expressions) and your string contains unescaped magic characters. However, even knowing that I found myself surprised by your results.

It's easier to see what gsub is doing if we change the replacement string:

```
string.gsub('+',   '--', '|') => |+|
string.gsub('+++', '--', '|') => |+|+|+|
```

`-` means "0 or more occurrences of the preceding atom". Unlike `+`, it's non-greedy, matching the fewest characters possible.

I just tested it and apparently "fewest characters possible" mostly means 0 characters. For instance, my intuition about this:

```
string.gsub('aaa','a-', '|')
```

Is that the expression `a-` would match each `a`, replace them with '|', resulting in '|||'. In fact, it matches on the 0-length gaps before and after each character, resulting in: '|a|a|a|'

In fact, it doesn't matter *what* atom we precede with `-`, it always matches on the smallest length, 0:

```
string.gsub('aaa','x-', '|') => |a|a|a|
string.gsub('aaa','a-', '|') => |a|a|a|
string.gsub('aaa','?-', '|') => |a|a|a|
string.gsub('aaa','--', '|') => |a|a|a|
```

You can see that last one is your case and explains your results. Your next result is the exact same thing:

```
string.gsub('+++','+-','|') => |+|+|+|
```

Your final result is more straightforward:

```
string.gsub('-+-+-+-','-+','|') => |+|+|+|
```

In this case, you're matching "1 or more occurances of the atom `-`", so you're just replacing the `-` characters, just as you'd expect.